# How to get the value of page item using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to show solutions for my errors and it will be based on the issue description keywords. This is my code. I have Issue Table and Solution Table. I have showed the error message on my page so I would like to enter the page item name for the value to be fetch however it is not working.

```
SELECT SOLUTION_DESCRIPTION
FROM CC_APP_SOLUTION_TBL A
,CC_APP_ISSUES_TBL B
WHERE B.ISSUE_ID = A.SOLUTION_ID
AND A.SOLUTION_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'|| :P82_ERROR_MSG || '%'
ORDER BY POINTS DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, query you posted is a source for a report region. Why? Because, if it returns more than a single row (and it does, as you said that you're trying to show "solution**s**" (plural)), then it won't work otherwise.

Therefore, you'll have to put `P82_ERROR_MSG` into report's **Page items to submit** property. Otherwise, your query doesn't see its value in session state and returns *nothing*.

Comment: Hi there, actually the query is on my collapsible region. I have 5 collapsible region and I would like to show 1 solution on each collapsible.

Comment: This is the updated code I am trying to work on: SELECT SOLUTION_DESC 
      FROM CC_APP_SOLUTION_TBL A
       INNER JOIN CC_APP_ISSUES_TBL B
            ON A.ISSUE_ID = B.ISSUE_ID AND
               WHERE A.SOLUTION_DESC LIKE '%'||B.ISSUE_DESC|| '%'
                      ORDER BY POINTS DESC
                            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: I will rephrase my question. I would like to fetch solutions from database based on the string of the error. Or I can also get a particular string on the P82_ERROR_MSG and will lookup on the database which one of the solutions has the same keyword as the error string

Comment: like the error and solution has the same ID which is Issue ID

Comment: If I had to choose between report (efficient) and 5 different regions (inefficient), I'd choose a **report**. Whichever option you choose, my suggestion is still valid (at least, I believe so): put P82_ERROR_MSG into "Page items to submit" property.

Comment: The 5 regions are the requirement of my boss that's why. So I have to add a Dynamic action to put the P82_ERROR_MSG on Page items to submit property?

Comment: From my point of view, your boss is wrong. As of the property: it is placed right below region's query, so you don't need a dynamic action.